# Conditional Formatting statement issue

Tags: excel

I am getting the most bizarre outcome from a conditional format that I can't seem to solve. My statement is

```
=AND($C$1<6,$J6=$C$2)
```

Whereas C1 is a number, J6 is the first cell to be checked, and C2 is the number I need matched.

In all I would like the cell to format if C1 is less than 6 and the cell matches the text in C2.

It is currently highlighting 5 completely seemingly random cells that are not a match??

[image: Image of Spreadsheet]

Comment: By highlighting, you mean, formatting? Please include a screenshot of your spreadsheet.

Comment: My guess is there is a disconnect with the `Applies to:` range and the first Cell in the formula.  The formula needs to point to the first row in the Applies to range.

Comment: I added an image of exactly the situation. The highlighted cells are way down the list in J column, but the highlighted cells are currently 5 consecutive cells that contain the number "79969".

Comment: Since your `Applies to` starts in Row 1 you need your formula to start there also: `=AND($C$1<6,$J1=$C$2)`

Comment: Or Start your `Applies To` in Row 6: `$J$6:$J$1000`

Comment: Wow, what a joke. Thank you Scott, can't believe that screwed it all up. Now after looking at that I see the cells that were being highlighted are exactly 6 cells above the desired.

Comment: @ScottCraner I have discovered another issue. When I delete this data the formatting Applies To field remains unchanged, but when I paste a new set of value it totally changes the CF. Any way to have the CF remain in columns J:L?

Comment: @KevinP, please post your follow-up question under a new thread to make it easier for other visitors to find.